# How to delete the largest node in Binary search Tree

Tags: binary-search-tree

I am trying to delete the largest node in binary search tree, I thougth that these code below should be able to do it but for some reason it is not. Could someone help please!

```
public void remove() {
            Node current = root;

            while(true){
                Node parent = current;
                current = current.getRighChild();

                if (current == null){
                    parent.setRighChild(null);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void remove() 

        {
        root = deleteMax(root);
        }       

  private Node deleteMax(Node x ) {
    if (x.getRighChild() == null)
        {
        return x.getLeftChild();

        }
    x.setRighChild(deleteMax(x.getRighChild()));
    return x;
```

}

Answer (score -1):

In your code if the right node is empty you are still deleting it. Instead of deleting the current if it is the max. Try something like this:

```
removeLargest() {
            current = getRoot();
            rightNode == null;

            while (root.Right){
                   current == root.Right
            }
            if (current.left()){
               rotate()
            }
            current.delete()
        }
```

Comment: If the rightmost non-leaf node has a left child you need to rotate.

Comment: I just got it worked recursively.  Maybe you can take a look at it to see if there is any bug.